# How can I increase the performance of scalar functions in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my table view i have 4 scalar functions to be called.
eg:

```
CREATE view [SUMMARY]
AS 

SELECT  [Code] ,
    ...
    dbo.[udf_REPORTTYPE](ts.LegTankSystemId,ReportingDate,analysis.[AnalysisTypeName]) as ReportingType ,   
    dbo.[udf_WATER](ts.SystemId,LastObsDate) as WaterReading,
    case when analysis.LastObsDate is null then NULL else dbo.[udf_BJs_GENERAL](ts.LegTankSystemId,ISNULL(analysis.LastObsDate, ssd.ReportingDate)) end as [1Plus130_Reslut],
  (CASE  WHEN State ='NY' THEN dbo.[udf_NY](ts.SystemId,LastObsDate)
         WHEN State ='CT' THEN dbo.[udf_CT] (ts.SystemId,LastObsDate)
    END) AS State_SIR_Result
FROM LOBDW.SITE dimsite
LEFT JOIN [bjs].[udv_TANK] ts on dimsite.SiteId = ts.SiteId
```

...

In those scalar function I read same parameter and doing different calculations.

To return 400 rows My view takes more than 1 minute. It is really bad.
How Can I improve the performance of those scalar functions? Is there a way to define global variable from one function and use that in another function if both functions requires same data?

eg function;

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_REPORTTYPE]
    (
      @TankSystemId int,
      @TimeStamp datetime2(7),
      @AnalysisTypeName varchar(10)
    )
RETURNS varchar(10)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReportType varchar(10);
    DECLARE @TimePeriod datetime2(7)
    DECLARE @LatestAnalysisDate datetime2(7)

    SELECT TOP 1 @TimePeriod = Date FROM udv_DailySiraData  where TankSystemId=@TankSystemId  ORDER BY Date DESC
    SELECT TOP 1 @LatestAnalysisDate = LastObsDate FROM [udv_ANALYSES] where TankSystemId =@TankSystemId  ORDER BY LastObsDate DESC

    SET @ReportType=@AnalysisTypeName
    IF ((@TimePeriod>=@TimeStamp) AND (@LatestAnalysisDate < @TimeStamp) AND @AnalysisTypeName IS NULL)
         SET @ReportType = 'No Analysis Result';
    IF ((@TimePeriod>=@TimeStamp) AND @AnalysisTypeName IS NULL)
         SET @ReportType = 'Latest';

    RETURN @ReportType;
END;
```

Comment: Do you have any I indexes defined 9n the tables you are using in your View?

Comment: @MarkKram No indexes yet. But I try to optimize my functions and see the performance then will try to  do index ing..Is there a way to define global variable from one function and use that in another function if both functions requires same data?

Comment: Don't use them. Look into using [CTEs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) instead.

Comment: @codeConcussion Any sample how can i replace functions with CTE?

Comment: @codeConcussion Looks performance wise CTE is bit worse than functions?

Comment: The problem with your functions is that they perform extra queries, and to make it worse you execute another 2-4 functions per row (which I suppose also perform extra queries), and since the functions are executed by *each* row if for example the query returns 100 more rows that mean 200-800 more *queries*, which degrades performance a lot. With a CTE you put all the logic in one query and then join with that query. Another option is using `APPLY` as in the answer by @Squirrel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can convert your UDF to OUTER APPLY , something like this

```
SELECT  [Code] ,
    ...
    --dbo.[udf_REPORTTYPE](ts.LegTankSystemId,ReportingDate,analysis.[AnalysisTypeName]) as ReportingType ,   -- change from UDF to Outer Apply
    RT.ReportingType,
    dbo.[udf_WATER](ts.SystemId,LastObsDate) as WaterReading,
    case when analysis.LastObsDate is null then NULL else dbo.[udf_BJs_GENERAL](ts.LegTankSystemId,ISNULL(analysis.LastObsDate, ssd.ReportingDate)) end as [1Plus130_Reslut],
    (CASE  WHEN State ='NY' THEN dbo.[udf_NY](ts.SystemId,LastObsDate)
        WHEN State ='CT' THEN dbo.[udf_CT] (ts.SystemId,LastObsDate)
    END) AS State_SIR_Result
FROM    LOBDW.SITE dimsite
    LEFT JOIN [bjs].[udv_TANK] ts on dimsite.SiteId = ts.SiteId
    OUTER APPLY -- convert from udf_REPORTTYPE
    (
        SELECT  ReportingType = 
                CASE    WHEN    MAX(x.DATE)    >= ssd.ReportingDate 
                        AND     MAX(y.LastObsDate) <  ssd.ReportingDate 
                        AND     analysis.[AnalysisTypeName] iS NULL
                        THEN    'No Analysis Result'
                        WHEN    MAX(x.DATE)    >= ssd.ReportingDate 
                        AND     analysis.[AnalysisTypeName] iS NULL
                        THEN    'Latest'
                        ELSE    analysis.[AnalysisTypeName]
                        END
        FROM    udv_DailySiraData x
            INNER JOIN udv_ANALYSES y   ON  x.TankSystemId  = y.TankSystemId
        WHERE   x.TankSystemId  = ts.LegTankSystemId
    ) RT
```

Comment: Thank you this increases performance a lot. may I know how this outer apply increase the perfomance?

Comment: If I use more than one functions, Can I use this OuterApply more than once, How the performance will be? eg: OUTER APPLY -- convert from udf_REPORTTYPE
    (
     ) RT OUTER APPLY -- convert from udf_WATER
    (
     ) WA

Answer (score 1):

Here's a CTE alternative to the OUTER APPLY, although I'm sure that works just fine...

```
WITH TimePeriods AS (
    SELECT
        TankSystemId,
        TimePeriod = MAX(Date)
    FROM
        udv_DailySiraData
    GROUP BY
        TankSystemId
), AnalysisDates AS (
    SELECT
        TankSystemId,
        LatestAnalysisDate = MAX(LastObsDate)
    FROM
        udv_ANALYSES
    GROUP BY
        TankSystemId
)
SELECT
    ...
    ReportingType =
        CASE
            WHEN tp.TimePeriod >= ReportingDate AND ad.LatestAnalysisDate < ReportingDate AND analysis.AnalysisTypeName IS NULL THEN 'No Analysis Result'
            WHEN tp.TimePeriod >= ReportingDate AND analysis.AnalysisTypeName IS NULL THEN 'Latest'
            ELSE analysis.AnalysisTypeName
        END,
    ...
FROM
    LOBDW.SITE dimsite
LEFT JOIN
    bjs.udv_TANK ts
    ON dimsite.SiteId = ts.SiteId
LEFT JOIN
    TimePeriods tp
    ON ts.LegTankSystemId = tp.TankSystemId
LEFT JOIN
    AnalysisDates ad
    ON ts.LegTankSystemId = tp.TankSystemId
```

Comment: Thank you...Ill give a try and see the performance. I tried outer apply as squirrel mentioned, It increases the performance.